# javascript google visualization selection option

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I tried to use google spreadsheet to realize drop-down select option!
But I encounter some errors...
In console,it shows that...

```
**A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart%2Cgeomap%2Ctable, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.**
**A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/b5ac9efed10eef460d14e653d0…zh_TW,default+zh_TW,ui+zh_TW,geomap+zh_TW,table+zh_TW,corechart+zh_TW.I.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.**
```

I try the tips to fix it, but it can't fix...
Here is the code I have written

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
google.setOnLoadCallback(runQuery);
google.load('visualization', '1',
        {
          'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']
        }
);function runQuery() {
var tableid = '1zCrjWMRxcedcvdWWAwtc9psQoK8GoGyxy8R53Ga_ztk#gid=0';
var uri = "SELECT geometry FROM " + tableid ;
var queryText = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=" + encodeURIComponent(uri);
var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
query.setQuery("select B");
var a = query.setQuery("select B,C,D ");
query.send(function(resp){
if (!resp.isError()) {
  var dataTable = resp.getDataTable();
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(dataTable.toJSON());
  var len = jsonData.rows.length;
  console.log(len);
  alert(len);
  }
});}</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**1)** the `Parser-blocking` message should be just a warning.

regardless, to avoid the message, use `loader.js` to load the library,
instead of the older library `jsapi`

you will need to change the `load` statement, as follows...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(runQuery);
...
```

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

**2)** suspect there is another error occuring, check the response messages

see following working snippet, when i run it, the error is `Access denied`...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(runQuery);

function runQuery() {
var tableid = '1zCrjWMRxcedcvdWWAwtc9psQoK8GoGyxy8R53Ga_ztk#gid=0';
var uri = "SELECT geometry FROM " + tableid ;
var queryText = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=" + encodeURIComponent(uri);
var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryText);
query.setQuery("select B");
var a = query.setQuery("select B,C,D ");
query.send(function(resp){
if (!resp.isError()) {
  var dataTable = resp.getDataTable();
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(dataTable.toJSON());
  var len = jsonData.rows.length;
  console.log(len);
  } else {
    console.log('Error: ' + resp.getMessage() + '\nDetails: ' + resp.getDetailedMessage());
  }
});}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38666678/5090771) of creating a drop down from a spreadsheet -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38613267/5090771) of using filters on a spreadsheet

Comment: I have tried your suggestions,there is no error,however the page is empty.

Comment: makes sense, the `dataTable` is retrieved but never used for anything, what did you expect to appear?

Comment: And I found a serious problem: the protected spreadsheet is to prevent some data to seeing by others, but I can't access...
Once I can access the protected spreadsheet, how do I avoid other access it...?

Comment: not sure, can you make it read-only for everyone else? sounds like the topic for another question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665509/building-populating-a-drop-down-menu-on-web-page-from-google-spreadsheet-data/38666678#38666678
I have try this, and this work! But I have a question that I can not use sql query...how to fix it?

Comment: not sure what you mean by _can not use sql query_ -- looks like you're using `query.setQuery('select...')` above...?

Comment: yes! when I use this, it shows that un defined ids!

Comment: The function what I want is that: That is a form about select address! There are three selection: City, Area, Street! When I select City's option, then Area's option is also show, and Area's option is related to City's  option! Most important thing is that City, Area and Street 's option is the google spreadsheet ! I can write code to Select column! But I don't know how to write it through google visualization api... that is the question what I want to know... Please help me ...

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thanks, mate! You win the Internet today.